# How can I more rigorously check for errors at design or compile-time when using rollup.js in a Svelte app?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, svelte, rollupjs

(Please excuse any naivety about this question, I'm not sure if it's significant whether or not I'm using Svelte)

I'm using rollup.js as the compiler for a Svelte app which uses ES2015. I'm not seeing anything that will warn me if it's possible for a value to be undefined (or warn me about any other potential deficiencies of the code), other than an ordinary compile failure. Is there a way to catch defects earlier, so I don't need to discover them at run-time? For example is there anything that gives me [Stylecop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop)-like capability? Or can I somehow configure a less forgiving compilation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Typescript. Here's an [article](https://codechips.me/how-to-use-typescript-with-svelte/) about how to incorporate it with Svelte.

Once you've got it working, you can set strict compilation rules for Typescript so that it will warn you about errors and type issues before letting you compile.